# How to check which page a form was submitted on in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using a comments model in several associations to other models. The relationship is always the same: a comment "belongs to" one other model's item, and those other models "have many" comments.

I am rendering the comment form on the other models' show pages like so:

```
<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, I would like him to be redirected to different pages, depending on which page he was on before. As I searched for a solution I found the `current_page?` ActionView helper via APIdock (cf. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) and thought it was a good idea to use it in the comments controller like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if (@comment.save) && (current_page?(controller: 'game', action: 'show'))
    format.html { redirect_to game_comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
  elsif (@comment.save) && (current_page?(controller: 'comment'))
    format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

But sadly I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `current_page?' for #<CommentsController:0x007f67fe42e1a0>
```

I would appreciate if someone can present me a solution on how I can find out, on which page a particular form was submitted on, or at least a way on how to redirect users to different pages then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_page?` is a view helper, so it's not available in controller.

you can get refer url by `request.referrer` in controller

Comment: Thank you for the tip. How can I debug what kind of result the method shows me? I changed my code to: `if (@comment.save) && (URI(request.referer).path == '/games')` but when I try it out it uses the "else" branch instead because the result does not fit.

Comment: you can try adding `puts URI(request.referer).path` in the controller and then see the exact path in the terminal